# Error - Zoom in D3 map - d3.behavior is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've started to study D3 a few days, and I'm trying to add a zoom feature for a map that I did.

I'm using [this example as a basis](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8fadc5ac9c2a9e7c5ba2), but when I try to adapt to my map I receive this error, and my map disappears

```
TypeError: d3.behavior is undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale((width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .classed("svg-cont", true)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 560 350")
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
    .append("g");

svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);
```

And below

```
function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: You're using D3 v4. There is no `d3.behavior.zoom` in v4, it's just `d3.zoom`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out, I was using an old version of D3. With d3.v4, I found that all I need to do is insert

```
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
```

So I got:

```
var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 700 300")
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }));
```

And it works!